# Вывод списка всех опций

Tags: php, opencart

Подскажите. есть ли функционал на получение всех опций и только их? может есть модуль какой.

есть опции для товаров. эти опции можно подцепить к товарам. это не вопрос и получить опции у данного товара тоже нет проблем.
А мне нужно получить все опции и их значения без привязки к какому либо товару.

Answer (score 0):

В моделе добавьте метод (например, в catalog/product, не суть):

```
public function getAllOptions() {

    $option_value_description = array();

    $option_value_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "option_description WHERE language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY option_id ASC");

    foreach ($option_value_query ->rows as $option){
        $option_value_description_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value_description WHERE option_id = " . $option['option_id'] . " AND language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY option_value_id ASC");
        $option_value_description[$option['name']] = $option_value_description_query->rows;
    }

    return $option_value_description;
}
```

Где-нибудь в контроллере вызовите метод модели:

```
$this->load->model('catalog/category'); //подключение модели
....
$all_options = $this->model_catalog_product->getAllOptions();
```

В результате получите массив опций:

```
Array(
[опция1] => Array(
        [0] => Array
            (
                [option_value_id] => ...
                [language_id] => ...
                [option_id] => ...
                [name] => ...
            )

        [1] => ...
[опция2] => Array( ...
....
```